# Inserting text in the image between two columns

Tags: graphics, floats

How do I insert an image from text in two columns so that the text go around the picture?[image]

Comment: [`wrapfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) should be able to do this with some "manual intervention". See [How to use `wrapfig` to span multiple columns](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/multiple-span.txt).

Comment: You really should provide more information with your questions, otherwise you run the risk of making the impression that you're not willing to do any research by yourself. How do you generate the shape (is it an image, is it a TikZ shape)? Why did other solutions (like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/very-specific-paragraph-shape) not work for you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Werner mentioned, the `wrapfig` package can do this sort of thing; a little example (you can replace the black rectangle with an image or a `\parbox` containing text, for example):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newcommand\Text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.}

\begin{document}

\Text\Text\Text
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{r}[\dimexpr.5\width+.5\columnsep\relax]{6cm}
  \centering
  \rule{5cm}{2.5cm}
\end{wrapfigure}%
\Text\Text\Text\Text\Text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Lorem ipsum 
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{l}[\dimexpr.5\width+.5\columnsep\relax]{6cm}
\vfill
\end{wrapfigure} 

 \noindent dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.\Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

The exact instructions on how to produce this type of layout can be found in the file [multiple-span.txt](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/multiple-span.txt).

I don't know a package allowing to easily create circular cutouts (`shapepar` could be an option but I've never used it), but using the `\parshape` primitive is possible (with some effort) to manually produce a circular cutout and then use, for example, `TikZ` to place some material; a little example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\parshape16 0cm \linewidth 
0cm \linewidth 
0cm \linewidth 
0cm \linewidth 
0cm \dimexpr\linewidth-1.1cm\relax
0cm \dimexpr\linewidth-1.6cm\relax
0cm \dimexpr\linewidth-1.9cm\relax
0cm \dimexpr\linewidth-2.15cm\relax
0cm \dimexpr\linewidth-2.25cm\relax
0cm \dimexpr\linewidth-2.27cm\relax
0cm \dimexpr\linewidth-2.25cm\relax
0cm \dimexpr\linewidth-2.15cm\relax
0cm \dimexpr\linewidth-1.9cm\relax
0cm \dimexpr\linewidth-1.6cm\relax
0cm \dimexpr\linewidth-1.1cm\relax
0cm \linewidth
\lipsum[1-3] 
\parshape16 0cm \linewidth 
0cm \linewidth 
0cm \linewidth 
0cm \linewidth 
1.1cm \dimexpr\linewidth-1.1cm\relax
1.6cm \dimexpr\linewidth-1.6cm\relax
1.9cm \dimexpr\linewidth-1.9cm\relax
2.15cm \dimexpr\linewidth-2.15cm\relax
2.25cm \dimexpr\linewidth-2.25cm\relax
2.27cm \dimexpr\linewidth-2.27cm\relax
2.25cm \dimexpr\linewidth-2.25cm\relax
2.15cm \dimexpr\linewidth-2.15cm\relax
1.9cm \dimexpr\linewidth-1.9cm\relax
1.6cm \dimexpr\linewidth-1.6cm\relax
1.1cm \dimexpr\linewidth-1.1cm\relax
0cm \linewidth
\lipsum[1]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill[blue!30] ($(current page.center)+(0,-2.1cm)$) circle [radius=63pt,fill=blue!30];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And circle shape is also possible?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: see my updated answer.

Comment: Dimensions as you draw the circle? Manually?

Comment: And if one column? How to do?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: in that case, I think the most sensible option would be to use the `shapepar` package. I think that this new requirement might deserve opening a new question.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: And answering your question about the circle dimensions, yes I obtained them manually (as I said in my answer). I first placed the circle in its final position and then used `\parshape` to manually produce the desired cutout.