# Paracol and wrapfig

Tags: wrapfigure, paracol

I would like to put a figure between two columns using `paracol`, exactly like the answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34435. Note that this linked example uses `twocolumn` document class, whereas I want a `paracol`. How can I accomplish this? I paste the example from the link here:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\newcommand\Text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.}

\begin{document}

\Text\Text\Text
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{r}[\dimexpr.5\width+.5\columnsep\relax]{6cm}
  \centering
  \rule{5cm}{2.5cm}
\end{wrapfigure}%
\Text\Text\Text\Text\Text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Lorem ipsum 
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{l}[\dimexpr.5\width+.5\columnsep\relax]{6cm}
\vfill
\end{wrapfigure} 

 \noindent dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.\Text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way, the only difference is that you need to switch the column

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{paracol}

\newcommand\Text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.}

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\begin{paracol}{2}
\Text \Text
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{r}[\dimexpr.5\width+.5\columnsep\relax]{6cm}
  \centering
  \rule{5cm}{2.5cm}
\end{wrapfigure}%
\Text \Text
\switchcolumn
\Text \Text
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{l}[\dimexpr.5\width+.5\columnsep\relax]{6cm}
\vfill
\end{wrapfigure} 
\Text \Text
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]