# Text wrap with shapepar (insert image between text)

Tags: graphics, wrap, shapepar

How do insert image between text and text wrap with shapepar or other package?
[image]

Comment: Although this is not an exact duplicate, the following post should guide you through the steps using [Xfig](http://www.xfig.org/): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/very-specific-paragraph-shape.

Comment: I used the steps in the link that you passed, but I can not subtract the signal section with -. It does not work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use package `cutwin` and run the example with `xelatex` because I use an eps image as vector graphic which has no background. Using a png image with clipping may also be possible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cutwin,graphicx,pstricks,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\opencutcenter
\newcommand\Margins{%
0.4\textwidth, 0.4\textwidth,
0.35\textwidth, 0.35\textwidth,
0.32\textwidth, 0.32\textwidth,
0.3\textwidth, 0.3\textwidth,
0.28\textwidth, 0.28\textwidth,
0.26\textwidth, 0.26\textwidth,
0.26\textwidth, 0.26\textwidth,
0.28\textwidth, 0.28\textwidth,
0.3\textwidth, 0.3\textwidth,
0.32\textwidth, 0.32\textwidth,
0.35\textwidth, 0.35\textwidth,
0.4\textwidth, 0.4\textwidth}
\renewcommand\putstuffinpic{%
  \rput(0,-5\normalbaselineskip){%
    \includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{tiger}}}
\begin{shapedcutout}{2}{12}{\Margins}% 2 normal lines, 12 shaped lines
\lipsum[1]
\end{shapedcutout}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 30):

Here is a similar play-by-play of what was described by @KarlOveHufthammer in his [excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/very-specific-paragraph-shape/33071#33071) regarding the [coat-of-arms construction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/very-specific-paragraph-shape) using [Xfig](http://www.xfig.org/). I'm running Windows 7 with [Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/), and is therefore also able to use Xfig (version `3.2.5b`). I also have `transfig` (version `3.2.5c-1`, also called `fig2dev`) installed as part of the [Cygwin/X distribution setup](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe):

1. Open Xfig and set up a comfortable view/zoom level that is detailed enough. It does not have to be perfect, since LaTeX will resize the paragraph shape as specified using `\shapepar` to match whatever text you want to put into it.

   [image]
2. Draw the outer shape of the paragraph. In this case I used the rectangle tool to draw a square.

   [image]
3. Once complete, edit the rectangle and add the comment "`+`" (without the quotes).

   [image]
4. Now draw the interior cut-out shape. In this case I used the circle tool.

   [image]
5. Once complete, edit the rectangle and add the comment "`-`" (without the quotes).

   [image]
6. Save the image in Xfig format as (say) `myshape.fig`.

   [image]

   The Xfig file looks like this:

   ```
   #FIG 3.2  Produced by xfig version 3.2.5b
   Landscape
   Center
   Inches
   Letter  
   100.00
   Single
   -2
   1200 2
   # -
   1 3 0 1 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 1 0.0000 3000 3000 1500 1500 3000 3000 4500 3000
   # +
   2 2 0 1 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 0 0 -1 0 0 5
        0 0 6000 0 6000 6000 0 6000 0 0
   ```
7. Execute:

   ```
   fig2dev -L shape -n myshape myshape.fig myshape.shape
   ```

   The flag `-L` sets the output language used to `shape` (that conforms to `shapepar`). Other languages also exist, but this option should be specified *first*. The flag `-n` sets the name to be used within the output file `myshape.shape`. So, using `-L shape -n <name>` will create `\<name>par`. The output `myshape.shape` from `myshape.fig` now contains the  newly-created macro `\myshapepar{<par>}` where the paragraph definition in "`shape` language" is given by `\myshapeshape`:

   ```
   \def\myshapepar#1{\shapepar{\myshapeshape}#1\par}
   \def\myshapeshape{%
   {25.0833}%
   {0.0833333}b{0.0833333}\\%
   {0.0833333}t{0.0833333}{50}\\%
   {12.5833}t{0.0833333}{25}st{25.0833}{25}\\%
   {12.6667}t{0.0833333}{23.3333}t{26.75}{23.3333}\\%
   {13.0833}t{0.0833333}{21.6667}t{28.4167}{21.6667}\\%
   {13.5833}t{0.0833333}{20}t{30.0833}{20}\\%
   {14.4167}t{0.0833333}{18.5}t{31.5833}{18.5}\\%
   {15.4167}t{0.0833333}{17.0833}t{33}{17.0833}\\%
   {16.5833}t{0.0833333}{15.8333}t{34.25}{15.8333}\\%
   {17.8333}t{0.0833333}{14.75}t{35.3333}{14.75}\\%
   {19.3333}t{0.0833333}{13.9167}t{36.1667}{13.9167}\\%
   {20.9167}t{0.0833333}{13.25}t{36.8333}{13.25}\\%
   {22.5}t{0.0833333}{12.75}t{37.3333}{12.75}\\%
   {24.25}t{0.0833333}{12.5}t{37.5833}{12.5}\\%
   {25.9167}t{0.0833333}{12.5}t{37.5833}{12.5}\\%
   {27.6667}t{0.0833333}{12.75}t{37.3333}{12.75}\\%
   {29.25}t{0.0833333}{13.25}t{36.8333}{13.25}\\%
   {30.8333}t{0.0833333}{13.9167}t{36.1667}{13.9167}\\%
   {32.3333}t{0.0833333}{14.75}t{35.3333}{14.75}\\%
   {33.5833}t{0.0833333}{15.8333}t{34.25}{15.8333}\\%
   {34.75}t{0.0833333}{17.0833}t{33}{17.0833}\\%
   {35.75}t{0.0833333}{18.5}t{31.5833}{18.5}\\%
   {36.5833}t{0.0833333}{20}t{30.0833}{20}\\%
   {37.0833}t{0.0833333}{21.6667}t{28.4167}{21.6667}\\%
   {37.5}t{0.0833333}{23.3333}t{26.75}{23.3333}\\%
   {37.5833}t{0.0833333}{25}jt{25.0833}{25}\\%
   {50.0833}t{0.0833333}{50}\\%
   {50.0833}e{50.0833}%
   }
   ```
8. Create and compile your TeX file:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{shapepar}% http://ctan.org/pkg/shapepar
   \usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
   \input{myshape.shape}% Contains \myshapepar{<par>}
   \begin{document}
   \myshapepar{\lipsum*[1-3]}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   As mentioned, the size of the shape is not necessary. If you supply `\lipsum*[1]` instead (a shorter paragraph text), the output resembles:

   [image]

   Also note the use of `\lipsum*`. `\shapepar` does not allow the use of `\par`. Line breaking is achieved using `\\`.

Image insertion is achieved with an overlay, by moving the image to appropriate position using horizontal/vertical skips or otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, is not working because I could not install the transfig plugin in Ubuntu.

Comment: With the shape defined already in the code above, you can just use it without having to install `transfig`. The answer merely shows how it can be achieved. In your specific case, the answer (shape-wise) matches your post exactly.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: Your original question shows the shape of a square-ish block with a circle in the middle that has the text removed. That shape is contained in my answer. If that is sufficient for your purpose, then you can use the code as provided. If you want the shape to be different (say, taller vertically, or with the cut-out circle not centered), then you either have to edit the `\myshapeshape` macro *manually* using the guidelines of the [`shapepar` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/shapepar/shapepar.pdf), or use the above steps to recreate an alternative shape.

Comment: You can override the command rput some other way to dispose of the package pstricks?

Comment: @Werner "Image insertion is achieved with an overlay...". Any pointers? Simply `\includegraphics`, that is?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris: You could use [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and it's `remember overlay` specification; [`textpos`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) or [`esopic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/esopic). Any one of those would work. Alternatively you could make the image non-existent (in terms of its real estate and then push it left/right up/down into position (`\smash{\raisebox[<down>]{<up>}{\makebox[0pt]{\hspace{<left>}\includegraphics{...}\hspace{<right>}}}}`).