# Error shapepar to use the command \circleshape

Tags: graphics, wrap, shapepar

See my code: With `\diamondshape` it works but with `\circleshape` it does not. What is wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\shapepar{\circleshape}
{\lipsum*[1]}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use English rather than Latin or use hyphenation for Latin via the babel package and the overflow problem would go away!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\shapepar[8.5cm]{\circleshape}
\lipsum*[1]
\end{document}
```

This will also work, that points certainly that there is some sort of overflow due to hyphenation not being achieved.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\begin{document}
\shapepar[8.5cm]{\circleshape}
a an ann anne lo res ar t t \lipsum*[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: ...interesting!

Comment: @Werner ...TeX's mysteries! At first I thought it was an expansion problem, but then I realized it uses the fp package...

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly sure why, but LaTeX complains about a dimension being too large. My guess is this has to do with the top and bottom end of the circle. Using a similar approach to that specified in [Text wrap with shapepar (insert image between text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34546/text-wrap-with-shapepar-insert-image-between-text), here is a new versions of `\circleshape` called `\mycircleshape`. I've written it into a macro so you can use `\mycircle{\lipsum*[1]}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shapepar}% http://ctan.org/pkg/shapepar
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\mycircle}[1]{\shapepar{\mycircleshape}#1\par}
\def\mycircleshape{%
{25.1393}%
{0.0696379}b{25.1393}\\%
{0.278552}t{21.727}{6.82451}\\%
{0.97493}t{18.3844}{13.5097}\\%
{2.15877}t{15.1811}{19.9164}\\%
{3.69081}t{12.117}{26.0446}\\%
{5.71031}t{9.33148}{31.6156}\\%
{8.00836}t{6.82451}{36.6295}\\%
{10.6546}t{4.66574}{40.9471}\\%
{13.5794}t{2.85515}{44.5682}\\%
{16.7131}t{1.53203}{47.2145}\\%
{20.0557}t{0.626741}{49.0251}\\%
{23.3983}t{0.139276}{50}\\%
{26.8802}t{0.139276}{50}\\%
{30.2228}t{0.626741}{49.0251}\\%
{33.5655}t{1.53203}{47.2145}\\%
{36.6992}t{2.85515}{44.5682}\\%
{39.624}t{4.66574}{40.9471}\\%
{42.2702}t{6.82451}{36.6295}\\%
{44.5682}t{9.33148}{31.6156}\\%
{46.5877}t{12.117}{26.0446}\\%
{48.1198}t{15.1811}{19.9164}\\%
{49.3036}t{18.3844}{13.5097}\\%
{50}t{21.727}{6.82451}\\%
{50.2089}e{25.1393}%
}

\begin{document}
\mycircle{\lipsum*[1]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to redefine, you need to expand the text. Try this `\shapepar{\circleshape}
this must have a reasonable  a reasonable number of words to achieve a circle.`

Comment: This still does not explain why `\lipsum*[1]` works for `\diamondshape` but not `\circleshape`.

Comment: @Werner Sure it does not but neither the answer:) I think Herbert identified the source of the error but still not the answer!

Answer (score 2):

there is a problem with the `\lipsum` macro. It redefines `\par` which isn't allow
inside shapepar

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\let\lips@par\endgraf
\makeatother   
\begin{document}

\shapepar[8.5cm]{\circleshape}
\lipsum[1]    

\shapepar[8.5cm]{\circleshape}
\lipsum*[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regis is using `\lipsum*` which doesn't emit `\par` commands.

Comment: According to the definition of `\lipsum*`, it should do exactly as you suggest: `\let\lips@par\relax` by executing `\ChangeLipsumPar` before typesetting the actual `\lipsum`. So why does it not work as expected?

Comment: Now I also use the star version

Answer (score 0):

If the error was "dimension too large" or "arithmetic overflow", that was a sporadic random occurrence. It was fixed in shapepar version 2.3 (Sep 2019).