# How to wrap one column text around a centered figure?

Tags: wrapfigure

Can I wrap one column text around a figure at the center of a page? The `wrapfig` package does not have a `c` option, and only refers to two columns text. Also on this site I see many questions about wrapping inside two columns and none about one column. Is there some technical reason why this isn't implemented?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Text wrap with `\shapepar` (insert image between text)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34546/5764)

Comment: @Werner yes but those are too much complicated, is there a simpler way?

Comment: If there was a simpler way, there would be answers incorporating them at that location, still making this a duplicate. When things "get complicated" in TeX, you should ask yourself the question whether it is really necessary. If it's complicated and you can make it work, then it's awesome, but you have to consider the trade-off between traditional typesetting techniques and something out-of-the-ordinary. I don't know what else to say...

Comment: There is also the `picins` package, but the documentation there is patchy (and I have not used it myself)

Comment: fixing the position of the insert at a fixed position on the page rather than tied to the text flow (as wrapfig does) is massively complicated in TeX (practically impossible without either severe restrictions on the text content or re-implementing most of latex)