# Shaped paragraph with centred picture (shapepar & cutwin)

Tags: paragraphs, wrap, parshape

I spent much time on this, but could not manage it or find a similar problem.

I would like to insert a picture in the center of this heart shaped paragraph, the text should be wrapped around it. 
[image]

That's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{cutwin}


\opencutcenter
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{\centering\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example.jpg}}

\begin{document}
\shapepar{\heartshape}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Any attempt with the package cutwin leads to huge crashes. For example the following:

```
\begin{cutout}{a}{b}{c}{d} 
\shapepar{\heartshape}
\lipsum[1]
\end{cutout}
```

Does anyone have a clue how to proceed? Thanks !

Comment: (edited) That document gives me an error message about `\cutout` being defined both in `shapepar` and `cutwin`. Other versions of one of both of those, or is that not really what you have used?

Comment: its basically what I used. To my knowledge cutwin is integrated in shapepar. When I leave \usepackage{cutwin} out, it doesn't recognize "\opencutcenter", which is needed to center the pic. I know it is not very elegant, but just pressing enter gives at least some output. Should be renamed MNWE..^^

Comment: Perhaps this answer from **Werner** could be useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34550/3954.

Comment: Are there any other packages (beside cutwin and shapepar) able to cutout or reflow text around shapes/images?

Comment: Have a look at [Flowfram user guide](http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/flowfram/ffuserguide.pdf)