# Image float around text

Tags: graphics, floats

I've searched the net for it, but couldn't find any method for LaTeX. Is it possible to make insert an image rounded by text? Like this strawberry?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Kind regards
Basilius Sapientia
[image: Strawberry]

Comment: shapepar package here http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/shapepar/shapepar.pdf you can see foe example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34546/text-wrap-with-shapepar-insert-image-between-text/34556#34556 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34546/text-wrap-with-shapepar-insert-image-between-text/34550#34550

Comment: or this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53073/two-column-text-with-circular-insert/70169#70169