# How to make text flow like this example

Tags: formatting, text

I have a few images I've like to put on a page with text, but instead of normal figures I'd like to the text to flow around the shape of the image like so:

[image]

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Look for ’shapepar’ package

Comment: Other options include: [Wrap text around an irregular shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245315/5764); [Text wrap with `shapepar` (insert image between text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34546/5764); ...