# Fill left and right with Words keeping figure in the centre

Tags: beamer

I was trying to design a frame in beamer as follows:

1. A graphics at center rendered by `tikzfill` within a polygon circle, ellipse etc.
2. And some text on left and right of the graphics to fill the blank area.

As I am unaware how to do it, providing a schema of the Idea, I am trying to replace the blue strockes by text:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzfill, lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \textbf{Upper Portion}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \path[fill stretch image=example-image-duck] (0,0) ellipse (30mm and 20mm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    \textbf{Lower Portion}
    A few sentences can be appended at last. This portion is auxiliary though.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Check out this thread https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245315/ and the links and packages mentioned.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401604/book-on-a-single-poster-page/403353

Comment: Duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34546/text-wrap-with-shapepar-insert-image-between-text/34550#34550