# "arrow down" shaped paragraph in LateX?

Tags: paragraphs, shapepar

I would like to shape some paragraph (using KOMA-script `scrbook` class with `two-column` option) to make it look like a down triangle (cul de lampe in French, do not know how this is called in English sorry). Something like:

```
 Some line here with full width but the width
 will shrink below until its very narrow etc... 
 Bla Bla some useless words in this dummy input
     To show eventually what I would like
          to do etc... etc... and so
              and so forth etc
                 etc etc to
                    end
```

I tried to use `shapepar` which comes with a down triangle or arrow shape but I cannot make it to limit the width to the column width. If the paragraph is long it overflows horizontally.

Perhaps it is duplicated but how then I can know (I mean automatically) the number of lines in the paragraph before it starts shrinking in width ? I mean in the example there are 3 full width lines but in real case I do not know how much there are. Only the triangle shape itself at the end is known.

Comment: Perhaps it is duplicated but how then I can know (I mean automatically) the number of lines in the paragraph before it starts shrinking in width ?

Comment: I think the English word for cul-de-lampe is *tailpiece*.

Comment: @Joseph: What about following the directions in [Text wrap with `shapepar` (insert image between text)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34550/5764)?