# How to adjust the horizontal position of a wrapped figure?

Tags: wrapfig

I have wrapped a text around a circular figure. I need to horizontally adjust the position of the figure by bringing it to the middle of page with text circularly wrapped around it.

`\hspace*{-5cm}\includegraphics`... is not working. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\begin{document}

\null\hfill\smash{
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip}{%
\includegraphics[width=2in]{magmag2.png}}}%
\par\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip}% 
\parshape 12 0pt 0.7\textwidth
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+4.5\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+3.75\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+3.25\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+3.00\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+3.0\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+3.20\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+3.5\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+4.25\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+6.0\baselineskip\relax
0pt \dimexpr0.5\textwidth+6.75\baselineskip\relax
0pt \textwidth
\noindent\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: magmag2]

[image]

Comment: it isn't clear what you mean by "bring to the middle of the page"? your parshape is making the text to the left of the figure more than half the text width in all cases. So what do you want to be in the middle? it would be easier if you showed  your current output then annotated it in an image editor to show what you want to move

Comment: My apologies for the inaccurate question. I added a picture of what I am trying to achieve. @david-carlisle

Comment: you can't do that with wrapfig or `\parshape` as neither can make a gap mid-line, there are I think answers on site showing approaches to this, I'll see if i can find one...

Comment: It is theoretically possible to do with \shapepar (shapepar package), but so far no joy.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34556/197451

Comment: I did not see this page before. It is simple and works great. I only had to add \tikzpicture. @js-bibra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based of a hole radius of 1.1in to provide some margin.  Note that lipsum has always been difficult to hyphenate.

I tried to set up `\holeshape` using pgfmath, but you can't use `\edef`.  OTOH, it should be possible to write the definition to a file and read it back.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}
\marginparsep=0.5in

\def\holeshape{{14.375}% h center
{0}b{0}\\
{0}t{0}{28.75}\\
{1}t{0}{11.566}st{17.184}{11.566}\\
{2}t{0}{10.029}t{18.721}{10.029}\\
{3}t{0}{9.0941}t{19.655}{9.0941}\\
{4}t{0}{8.4684}t{20.281}{8.4684}\\
{5}t{0}{8.0593}t{20.690}{8.0593}\\
{6}t{0}{7.836}t{20.924}{7.826}\\
{7}t{0}{7.750}t{20.999}{7.750}\\
{8}t{0}{7.836}t{20.924}{7.826}\\
{9}t{0}{8.0593}t{20.690}{8.0593}\\
{10}t{0}{8.4684}t{20.281}{8.4684}\\
{11}t{0}{9.0941}t{19.655}{9.0941}\\
{12}t{0}{10.029}t{18.721}{10.029}\\
{13}t{0}{11.566}jt{17.184}{11.566}\\
{14}t{0}{28.75}\\
{16}t{0}{28.75}\\
{16}e{28.75}}


\begin{document}
By using \verb|\baselineskip| as the scale, one can use $\sqrt{r^2-n^2}$ for $n=0,1,\dots$
to compute the offset startng at the center.

radius = \pgfmathparse{1.1in/\baselineskip}\pgfmathresult\par
text width = \pgfmathparse{\textwidth/\baselineskip}\pgfmathresult

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline=(origin)]
  \coordinate (origin) at (0,3pt);% ad hoc fudge factor
  \draw (0.5\textwidth,-7\baselineskip) circle[radius=1in];
\end{tikzpicture}%
\shapepar[\baselineskip]{\holeshape}\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: This code works for me. I used John's code with my picture in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\marginparsep=0.5in
\def\holeshape{{14.375}% h center
{0}b{0}\\
{0}t{0}{28.75}\\
{1}t{0}{11.566}st{17.184}{11.566}\\
{2}t{0}{10.029}t{18.721}{10.029}\\
{3}t{0}{9.0941}t{19.655}{9.0941}\\
{4}t{0}{8.4684}t{20.281}{8.4684}\\
{5}t{0}{8.0593}t{20.690}{8.0593}\\
{6}t{0}{7.836}t{20.924}{7.826}\\
{7}t{0}{7.750}t{20.999}{7.750}\\
{8}t{0}{7.836}t{20.924}{7.826}\\
{9}t{0}{8.0593}t{20.690}{8.0593}\\
{10}t{0}{8.4684}t{20.281}{8.4684}\\
{11}t{0}{9.0941}t{19.655}{9.0941}\\
{12}t{0}{10.029}t{18.721}{10.029}\\
{13}t{0}{11.566}jt{17.184}{11.566}\\
{14}t{0}{28.75}\\
{16}t{0}{28.75}\\
{16}e{28.75}}
\begin{document}
By using \verb|\baselineskip| as the scale, one can use $\sqrt{r^2-n^2}$ for 
$n=0,1,\dots$
to compute the offset starting at the center.
radius = \pgfmathparse{1.1in/\baselineskip}\pgfmathresult\par
text width = \pgfmathparse{\textwidth/\baselineskip}\pgfmathresult

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline=(origin)]
\coordinate (origin) at (0,3pt);% ad hoc fudge factor
\fill [white] (0.5\textwidth,-7\baselineskip) circle[radius=1in];
\node[inner sep=0pt] (magmag2) at (6,-3)[opacity=1]
{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{magmag2.png}
};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\shapepar[\baselineskip]{\holeshape}\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please keep in mind that imaginative layouts don't mix well with good typography. The space after "mauris." is horrendous and "fringilla" is nearly a margin note. Adding some like ` \usepackage[latin]{babel} \usepackage{microtype} \xspaceskip1ex\usepackage{microtype}\xspaceskip1ex` to the preamble can mitigate these effects, but there are not  fix for the annoying disrupt of the reading flow except remove the image.