# Tracing with xfig to make shapepar command

Tags: xfig

I'd like to create text/character shaped paragraphs similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160438). I've followed its [reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32997) and have been able to make simple shaped paragraphs with it, but I am unable to hand-trace any character (like $e$ or $\gamma$) to any reasonable degree. One of the comments on the reference mentions [AutoTrace](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/) but that program crashes on any input, even `-help`. I've also found an [online site](http://www.autotracer.org/) that can trace and output to a fig file, but all I get is a whole lot of unconnected points and no closed polygon shape. How can I trace/outline a shape (not by hand) in either xfig or elsewhere to make a polygon shape in xfig to then generate a `\shapepar` command?