# How to write a word within some text using Latex

Tags: text-decorations, text-manipulation

is it possible in latex to write a word within some text either by introducing a white figure and then wrapping the text around it or some other maybe more clever way. I want something like this, where I have tried using simple spacing to write "LA":

```
kesf kng k nrkeh ekrhgek elkrgn rkngel gnekgk bwngenw
alsmf kanskgna  sakng ksng-   a kang nknga kakg me fw
aklgn rgn ngsk  ks skgnd-  sl   nsgk dn ldgk nskgds l
dskg nlsrgn l-  rkgngrn           nrlnr nrkn rllsngrgj 
lfdnggnel rng-      ek   krgn kl   rkkf lrnmgl hfhj hj
ksgks lrnglkrg negk lke kenler lkerng ke nrkle ngrle l
```

I believe this question is similar to the following
[link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/very-specific-paragraph-shape).

however, in my case I am not interested in just any shape, but letters only. And I would like to be able to write any word of any length. Is there any tool out there that can do this task automatically instead of one having to define the length/shape of every letter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Unfortunately I do not understand what you're asking

Comment: @Moriambar: I think it's about inserting a text/white space box into some already typeset text? I don't know, it's only guessing. Or something with `\phantom{Fooooooooooooo}`?

Comment: @Moriambar - concentrate on the white space in the OP example - let your eyes focus on the distance - gradually the white upper case letters "LA" will appear.... :-)

Comment: You are looking for the `shapepar` package, but with more that one or two characters will be not a trivial task.

Comment: Like this:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32997/very-specific-paragraph-shape/33071#33071

Comment: @Thruston - you have understood the question correctly.